# Correcting Property/method errors

Tags: vba, methods, charts, properties, formatting

I have this Code and I keep getting Property / method errors on the same line. See below. Im pretty sure this is one of the last problems I need to take care of before I move on to fully run the code. Any and all help is much appreciated.

"volume CT" is the name of the ChartSheet

```
SC2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Volume CT").SeriesCollection.Count


For i = 1 To SC2 'Run the loop for all the data series [volume]
Debug.Print SC2 'make sure program counts correct amt of series

Dim name As String
    name = .FullSeriescollection(i).name
    Debug.Print name
End With

       'Find series names and change color for solids & area RedZone1
 resultx = InStr(1, name, x, vbTextCompare)
       'x is the variable name for the "codeWord" to look for
 Debug.Print resultx
 If resultx <> 0 Then
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Volume CT").Chart.SeriesCollection(i).ChartArea.Format.Fill
```

^^Error 438: Onject Does not support property or method

```
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = Red
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
End If
```

Comment: Does the `Sheets` object have a `Chart` object? In the first line, you're doing `Sheets("Volume CT").Series...`, but in the error line, your have `Sheets("Volume CT").` *Chart* `.Series...`

Comment: @TylerStandishMan almost. The `Sheets` object is a collection, and its `Item` getter (the default property implicitly being used here) returns an `Object`, so there's no IntelliSense beyond that. But the runtime type of the returned object is a `Chart` in this case... and indeed, a `Chart` object does not have a `Chart` member.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, thanks. I wasn't near a computer and haven't dealt with VBA in quite some time, but that seemed off to me, as your getting the object you're already referring to, just like you clarified.

Answer (score 2):

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Volume CT")` **is** a `Chart` object. And a `Chart` object does not have a `.Chart` member.

If you look at the *Project Explorer*, you'll see all your worksheets (and chart sheets) under *Microsoft Excel Objects*, along with `ThisWorkbook`.

Instead of accessing the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` collection and working late-bound against some `Object` returned by the implicit `Sheets.Item` getter you're using when you do `.Sheets("Volume CT")`, *use the chart object itself* - there *already* is a global reference to it, ready to be used:

[image: Microsoft Excel objects]

Just give it a meaningful name...

[image: Properties toolwindow]

...and then use it:

```
With WhateverTheChartNameIs.SeriesCollection(i).ChartArea.Format.Fill
```

---

Now, your instruction has 7 dots (`SeriesCollection(i)` is implicitly `SeriesCollection.Item(i)`), and with late-bound `Object` calls, that's quite a lot of dots: if you're not sure what types are involved and what their members are, this error 438 is bound to happen.

So you have a `Chart2` now, and you want to access a specific series; the `SeriesCollection.Item` property returns an `Object`, so instead of keeping the dots and writing code without knowing if the property actually exists, declare a variable for the series:

```
Dim s As Series
Set s = Chart2.SeriesCollection(i)
```

And then you can do

```
With s.ChartArrea.Format.Fill
```

But wait! A `Series` doesn't have a `ChartArea` property! What are we trying to do exactly? Format the *chart area* of the chart - why even bother with the `SeriesCollection` then?

```
With Chart2.ChartArea.Format.Fill 'notice you get IntelliSense all the way
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = Red
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

*Voilà!*

Comment: so This is something that I did not know and had not tried, thanks. Now i have: With Volume CT.SeriesCollection(i).ChartArea.Format.Fill

Comment: And the code is still not working, it says its expecting an ending to the expression or syntax error

Comment: You need to use the **name** *identifier* (the `(name)` property, as shown in the screenshot), not the "sheet name" - there are no spaces in a legal identifier.

Comment: @CoreyChung There are two names: the "code name" which is a global identifier you can use in code, and the "sheet name" which is shown in parentheses in the Project Explorer. You tried using the "sheet name".

Comment: I have now opened up the properties for the Chart sheet and replaced it with:
    With Chart2.SeriesCollection(i).ChartArea.Format.Fill

Now it still is not working but I am at least using the right name in the code now. Same property error

Comment: Yes same line, so now the code reads:
...
    resultq = InStr(1, name, q, vbTextCompare)
'q is the variable name for the "codeWord" to look for
    Debug.Print resultq
     If resultq <> 0 Then
         With Chart2.SeriesCollection(i).ChartArea.Format.Fill
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        'Bring to front option if visibilty is an issue
         End With
         Chart2.FullSeriescollection(i).SeriesType = xlLineMarkers
         End If
...

Comment: Comments are a bad place to put code in. Basically you're accessing the `SeriesCollection(i)` for no reason, just do `With Chart2.ChartArea.Format.Fill`, as I've edited my answer with.

Comment: Not for no reason - I just didnt specify the parameters of the original problem - the actions I require are repetative tho so I only included a piece for a timely response. 

WHAT I NEED: Is to change 4 types of series in a chart. 2 of which are area plots and red, one is area and green, and the last a line/marker style. So i do need to format each series individually, not the chart as a whole

Comment: Then declare a `Series` object and format that, don't work with the `ChartArea`. I believe you have everything you need to succeed now.